# UIAlertView doesn't slide up Automatically when keyboard appears on becomeFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, becomefirstresponder

I have subclassed `UIAlertView` and inside which I am showing a `textField` which takes the input. When user clicks on `textField` the keyboard shows up and `UIAlertView` moves up to adjust for keyboard. But when I do `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` in `didPresentAlertView` delegate method of `UIAlertView`, the alertView doesn't moves up to adjust for keyboard. Instead the `UIAlertView` gets hidden behind the keyboard.

PS - I know that Apple says that `UIAlertView` should not be subclassed and to be used as it is, but I am subclassing `UIAlertView` because I want to redesign the Apple's default UI elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really not do something against Apple's recommendation.

Reasons

1. You can face unexpected issues like the one you are facing.
2. Your code can break for future iOS releases as you are violating recommendations.
3. Redesigning Apple's standard controls is in violation of HIG guidelines. As a result, there is a chance that your app can get rejected. Create your own instead, by using `UIView` subclass.

As an alternative, Apple has made provision in the `UIAlertView` for this requirement. You don't need to add a textfield to the alert view, instead, use the `UIAlertView` property `alertViewStyle`. It accepts values defined in the enum [`UIAlertViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIAlertViewStyle)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIAlertViewStyle) {
    UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
    UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput, // Secure text input
    UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,  // Plain text input
    UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput // Two text fields, one for username and other for password
};
```

Example, lets assume a use case that you want to accept password from the user. The code to achieve this is as below.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter password"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput];
[alert show];
```

To validate the input, lets say password entered must be minimum 6 characters, implement this delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if( [inputText length] >= 6 )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

To get the user input

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
    {
        UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Password: %@", password.text);
    }
}
```

To re-iterate,
`UIAlertView` has a private view hierarchy and it is recommended to use it as-is without modification. If you use it against recommendation you will get unexpected results.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

This is standard technique used even in iOS default apps (Ex: Entering Wi-Fi password, etc.), hence using this will ensure you don't face issues like the one you mention.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do like this to upthe screen to show the textfiled. :-) Hope this help you.

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(( self.view.frame.origin.x), (self.view.frame.origin.y-50 ), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}


 - (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+50 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Comment: My question is shouldn't the `UIAlertView` move up automatically when I call `becomeFirstResponder`. The method you suggested is great and will obviously do the job but I was wondering that I should not be doing that, the `UIAlertView` will automatically do it.